# How frequently do you switch mode?

Tags: text-editor, vim, vi

I tried VIM and liked it but something stopped from using it: I had to type ESC to often, very often, something like each 5 seconds, and it was highly uncomfortable, so I stopped using it as a primary text editor (now I use emacs, nice for programmer as I am).

After my sad experience with VIM, I could get why some much intensive users love vim. But now I suppose that maybe, after a bigger training, the frequency of mode switching could decrease dramatically.

So, to verify this hypothesis, I am asking to you, old vim users, how frequently do you switch the mode?

Comment: Here is a list of some interesting VIM plugins for Web developers. These plugins surely saves a lot of time..
http://www.fortystones.com/vim-plugins-web-developers-programmers/

Answer (score 9):

I've been using vi/vim for nearly 30 years now, and I must say I've never found the mode switching an issue.  And you don't think emacs has modes????

As to your question, I really couldn't say. I suppose my work pattern is:

- open a file
- move around in command mode until I find the right place
- go into insert mode and write some text
- go into command mode and savethe file
- compile
- in command mode (note probably NOT in insert mode) fix syntax errors
- repeat as needed

So I tend to do reasonable sized blocks of work in each mode. It's not like I'm typing a character, switching to command, issuing a command, going to insert, typing another character.

Comment: emacs *doesn't* have modes, not in the sense of edit and command mode like vi.

Answer (score 9):

I can't tell you how often I switch modes, because it's almost second nature. It's not something I do consciously and I think most people agree on this. I did remap Caps Lock to Esc and it is much better, highly recommended.

Maybe the first week was like that as you paint it. I forced myself to use it for everything and it stopped being frustrating after a week. If you want to master it, I suggest the same. There are some good blog posts out there about setting up a comfortable environment (mainly about the tons of options configurable in .vimrc).

Comment: +1 "can't tell you how often...because it's almost second nature"

Comment: I like to map jj -> ESC.  Use the imap command.

Comment: how is that useful?

Comment: Scratch that, I tried and it's good :)

Answer (score 2):

I switch modes... always.  <kbd>Esc</kbd> is the most popular key on my keyboard.  Even in browser, typing this very message, I've hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> a couple of times, because it's already a habit.  And I don't care!  Smoking, for instance, would be a much worse habit.

However, if it really bothers you *that* much, I suggest you to see a shrink.

Answer (score 2):

Most vim users would be switching between insert and visual mode *all the time*. `Esc` does suck to type a often. [The day I started using Ctrl-c in place of Esc was the day my productivity increased tenfold.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69347/using-vi-with-modern-keyboards/69376#69376) I think reaching for the `Esc` key a lot would mildly strain my left hand too...

Comment: Do you feel the same about the quite frequently uses "1" key, located within millimetres of ESC on my keyboard?

Comment: @Neil: No, I don't. `Esc` is *much* further away from the `asdf` keys.

Comment: +1, for swapping Esc and Ctrl. I also liked switching Caps Lock with Ctrl, to make Ctrl easier to reach.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what I am doing.

When I'm banging out new code I am in Insert mode most of the time.

When I'm editing code on the PC I make use of the arrow keys quite a lot so I can stay in insert mode quite a lot. Its a bad habit, but one that's hard to break.

When coding on my iPhone over SSH, I don't have the arrow keys so have to come out of Insert mode pretty often to navigate.

You get used to it. Even when coding in Visual Studio I find myself pressing escape every 10 seconds.

Comment: "When coding on my iPhone over SSH" I sure hope this is a last ditch effort and not a regular thing.  I tried that a few times and could not manage to handle it.

Comment: @Chris, yeah we've just had a baby so I have to take whatever chances to code that I can get! I very rarely find myself in front of a laptop in my spare time any more.

Comment: I can totally understand that!

Answer (score 1):

The trick for me is to stay in command mode by default. Switch to insert/replace mode, enter text, switch straight back. If I leave the screen and come back, I'm in command mode; if I'm moving around the document, I'm in command mode. And so on.

That's not to say that I don't spend a fair amount of time in insert mode. It just means that while I'm there, I'm aware that I'm not in command mode and that I need to hit escape when I stop typing.

Why is this useful to you? What I quickly found is that I stop thinking of it as switching "modes" and started thinking of i/a/o (etc) as commands, which are followed by a string of characters and completed using ESC.

Answer (score 1):

You can remap ESC to whatever key combination you want :

I have the following code in my .vimrc :

```
" remap ESC to ii to avoid leaving home row to leave insert mode
" i to enter insert mode, ii to leave
inoremap ii <Esc>
vnoremap ii <Esc>
snoremap ii <Esc>
```

When you are in Insert, Visual or Select mode you can use 'ii' instead of ESC.

As long as you are not editing a file with variables containing 'ii' it works fine.

If I remember correctly, when Vi was developed the ESC key was at the same place that the CAPS lock on current keyboards. It was much easier to reach. As a consequence some people are using CAPS lock to switch mode.

Comment: Good, I will test soon.

Comment: This is language-dependent; I've seen a lot of "ii"s in assorted Finnish names, and suspect it's reasonably common in the language, so it would be a pain when typing comments also.

Comment: @David Thornley : I agree. Still it should be possible for any language to find a two key combination that should work. I have seen people mentioning `jk` as a replacement for escape. It works well too. ( And if all 2 keys combination are equally likely in your language of choice, you can use a 3 keys combination ). That being said I suppose that most people writing comments are usually writing them in English, since this is the lingua franca of our time, particularly for software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new VIM user, and switch modes just about as often. Though, I hasn't remapped my keys, the default secondary Ctrl-[ works well for me.

However, what I find important, isn't that I need to switch modes often. It's simply that I rarely need to switch context. When I'm working, I'm working, and the mechanics doesn't really matter.

Answer (score -2):

to change the mode ,you can use ctrl-[ to replace the esc

It will  work better! stick with it and you will done!